# Finding first and last occurence of substring and replace them with re.sub()

Tags: python-3.x

```
 import re

    def x(s):
        if re.match(r'^o|non', s):
            return re.sub(r'o|non', '', s, count=1)
        elif re.search(r'e|er|est$', s):
            return re.sub(r'(.*)e|er|est', r'\1''', s)
```

So if the string starts with '`o`' or 'non' the first occurence of one of those two will be replaced by `''`. Or if the string ends with `e`, `er` or `est` that ending will be replaced by `''`.

How can I write all this into one, so that if the string starts with 'non' and end with 'est' it will replace both of those and return the middle of the string. Also, I can't get this `(r'(.*)e|er|est', r'\1''', s)` to work, it only replaces the last e even if the string ends with `'est'`. Am I missing something or is the `'|'` not the way to go?

Answer (score 0):

You do not have to check for a mach first and you can chain both substitutions. Finally the end of a string is indicated by a `$` in regular expressions

```
 re.sub(r'e$|est$|er$' , '', re.sub(r'^o|^non','',s))
```

Comment: glad to be of help! Please accept the answer if the solution works for you.